# Check if update succeeded and echo

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a basic update query, I want to echo if it was successful so I've tried variations on this

```
$sql = 'UPDATE storeroom
    SET fruit=?
    WHERE stock_id =?
    AND stock_status <> \'supplied\'';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($v);

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
}

if ($count < 1) {
echo 'Unknown Stock ID or status change failed.';
}
else {
echo 'Status change successful.';
}
```

But it fails on the pg_affected_rows expecting a resource.

First time I'm using pg_affected rows [which I found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php)

If I substitute the affected rows for rowcount I get a different error

Comment: And what is `$dbh`? PDO connection?

Comment: Have you tried putting $stmt instead of $sql in pg_affected_rows($stmt);

Comment: Please make sure that you understand that PDO connection has nothing in common with `pg_` functions.

Comment: @u_mulder so I can't use pg_affected_rows to see if it updated successfully?

Comment: Obviously not, for PDO you should use [rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: On what variable do you call `rowCount`?

Comment: Where are the parameters for those placeholders?  What is `$v`?

Comment: `$sql` is a __string__. Please open the manual, __read it__. You will see that correct usage is `$stmt->rowCount()`.

Comment: We don't need to post another `rowCount()` answer -- we have plenty of pages on Stack Overflow that give this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try an alternative of `rowCount` - the SQL statement itself returns the number of updated rows.
Here is the SQL:

```sql
with t as
(
 UPDATE storeroom
    SET fruit = ?
    WHERE stock_id = ?
    AND stock_status <> 'supplied' 
    RETURNING stock_id 
) select count(*) from t;
```

and

```
$sql = <<<SQL
with t as
(
 UPDATE storeroom
    SET fruit = ?
    WHERE stock_id = ?
    AND stock_status <> 'supplied'
    RETURNING stock_id 
) select count(*) from t;
SQL;
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute($v);
$count = $stmt-> fetchColumn();
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this will do the trick, can depend on PHP version which I am not aware of:

```
$affected = $stmt->affected_rows;
```

Comment: `affected_rows` is for `mysqli` connection. We have found in comments that OP has PDO.

Comment: I have postgresql

Comment: oh, my bad, I missed that it is PDO